# Bash - iterate through output lines

Tags: bash

**What do I want**: find all the nginx access log files, iterate them (get some data from them).

I'm stuck at `for` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

logfiles="$(find /var/log/nginx -name 'access.log*')"

for lf in "$logfiles"
do
    echo "file"
done
```

Output is only one "file" word, despite of there are more than one log file. What's wrong?

Comment: Warning: `echo "file"` can not do different than echoing "file".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you say

```
for lf in "$logfiles"
```

your quotes preserve the whitespace within `find`'s output.  The quotes, in this case, are incorrect.  Removing them will properly iterate over the files:

```
$ for i in "`find . -iname '*.log'`"; do echo $i; done
./2.log ./3.log ./1.log

$ for i in `find . -iname '*.log'`; do echo $i; done
./2.log
./3.log
./1.log
```

But there's a much better way: you should *stream* your data instead of iterating.  Consider this pattern:

```
$ find . -iname '*.log' | xargs -n 1 echo
./2.log
./3.log
./1.log
```

It's very much worth wrapping your head around `xargs`, which turns its *standard input* into additional arguments to add to its own, which it then executes.  In this simple case, I'm telling xargs to run the command `echo` individually for each 1 (`-n 1`) of the files

There's a few reasons `xargs` is my go-to iteration operator whenever possible: firstly, it's very smart. Iterating over command output with `for i in $(command)` requires `$(command)` to provide your list in the form `item1 item2 item3`, causing problems if any of the items contain special characters, which are then *interpreted by bash as part of the for arguments*.

Here is an example of the space which typically becomes special in bash as a valid input field spearator.

```
$ for i in `find . -iname '*.log'`; do echo $i; done
./4
tricky.log
./2.log
./3.log
./1.log
```

the file `4 tricky.log`, containing a space, has now caused a problem.

`xargs` can be smart enough to keep them separate.  For some cases you can get around it with changing your `$IFS`, the input field separator.  But that gets messy fast.  With `xargs`, you have better options - specifially, `xargs` can also use the null character to terminate the items in its input stream with the `-0` character.  Other programs, namely `find`, can also use the null character in its output to match what `xargs` expects.  In this sense, `xargs` and `find` are a great combination:

```
$ find . -iname '*.log' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 echo
./4 tricky.log
./2.log
./3.log
./1.log
```

But wait, there's more!  The next step in your command will surely be to `grep` the files looking for whatever matching lines you wish to find.  If your lines are large, you'll want to parallelize too.  `xargs` can do this as well.  You can add more steps ot the pipeline for filtering etc.

Finally, using subshell substitution `$()` as program arguments can lead to unintended commands when not used very carefully to avoid unintentional arguments in failure cases.  I once wrote a script that used `$()` to find mysql's source directory to do some first-time setup.  It said something like `remove -r /$(find / -iname mysqldir)` .  Well, if there's no `mysqldir` in the expected location that turned into `rm -r /`.  Not what I intended, obviously: d'oh!

That's why I use and encourage others to use `xargs` whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

lose the quotes in this line: `for lf in $logfiles`
But it looks like you may have only one file named access.log

Comment: This answer is accurate, just not very detailed.  A proven example goes a long way!  I ran mine in bash before I posted just to make sure I was getting everything right - humans usually make bad parsers.

Comment: @DanFarrell Yes your answer is much more detailed as all answers should be. I did not have access to a terminal at the time and I wanted to comment rather than answer as I had not run it and could not provide detailed code. However, I did not have comment privileges at that time as my score was below 50 and I wanted to help OP as no one else had provided a solution at that time. Thank you for your feedback btw, I'll keep it in mind next time.